# Grabbing permission from facebook user and posting to their wall

Tags: php, facebook, api, permissions

Further to [Post to users wall upon facebook app submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965921/post-to-users-wall-upon-facebook-app-submission) (my old question), I have came up with the following code however it doesn't seem to be working?? I thought best to open a new question as it is a new question.

What am I doing wrong? Also, where should this code go?

```
<?php
$session = $facebook->getSession();

//Is user logged in and has allowed this app to access its data
if (!$session) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'canvas' => 1,
    'fbconnect' => 0,
    'next' => 'enter.php',
    'cancel_url' => 'index.php',
    ));    

//    use the $loginUrl created on the enter button to request permission;
}
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();


//post to wall
    $attachment = array('message' => '<message>',
                    'name' => '<name here>',
                    'caption' => '<caption here>',
                    'link' => '<link to app>',
                    'description' => '<enter description >',
                    'picture' => '<enter image url>',
                    'actions' => array(array('name' => '<enter action label>', 
                                      'link' => '<enter action url>')
                    );

    $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
    if( array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) ) {
// Permission is granted!
// Do the related task
try {
$post_id = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $attachment);
    } catch (CurlException $e) {
//timeout so try to resend
$post_id = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $attachment);
    } 
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
    }   
    } else {
// We don't have the permission
// Alert the user or ask for the permission!
    }

// store the post id in-case you need to delete later
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll just post the code I'm using that works. Hope it helps

> fbClass.php

```
    public function __construct() {
    // Naredimo instanco
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => $this->fbid,
                'secret' => $this->fbsecret,
                'cookie' => true,
            ));

    $this->facebook = $facebook;
}

function authUser($facebook) {

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
        try {
            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }
    }

    // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
    if (!($user)) {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                    'scope' => 'user_about_me, user_birthday, email, publish_stream',
                    'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/myappname/',
                ));
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

> process.php

```
$facebook = $fbClass->facebook;
$fbAuth = $fbClass->authUser($facebook);
if ($fbAuth) {

        $res = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', array(
                    'message' => MESSAGE,
                    'name' => NAME,
                    'caption' => '',
                    'description' => DESC,
                    'picture' => PIC,
                    'link' => 'http://www.facebook.com/myapp/',
                    'actions' => array('name' => 'Test', 'link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/')
                ));
        }
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I've tried that code but with no joy. What way have you set it up? How are you calling your code? Also, do you not need an access token?

Comment: Well, you have to use classes with it. `fbClass.php` starts with `class fbClass {
    
    private $fbid = "my app id";
    private $fbsecret = "secret";`

Then I include it in `process.php` with this:

`require 'classes/facebook-sdk/src/facebook.php';
require 'classes/fbClass.php';`

I create a new instance: `$fbClass = new fbClass();` and then call the functions: 
`$facebook = $fbClass->facebook;
$fbAuth = $fbClass->authUser($facebook);`

That's pretty much it.

Comment: Could you possibly post your full process.php and fbClass.php page? So I can get an understanding of how i'll implement it with my code? Also, where exactly should I call the process.php page? I have three main pages, index.php (button to enter app), enter.php (where the form is etc...), thankyou.php (thank you page.)

Comment: Well, I can't post you everything, since it's a big application. `request.php` is called with AJAX, but you can use the code that is in `request.php` in any other file. In your case, I'd say in enter.php or thankyou.php, depending what you want to achieve. There's not much of implementing, since `fbClass.php` is a standard class and `request.php` is just a file with some logic (I have a lot of other irrelevant code in it). Do you get any errors that might help me understant your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm just a little confused. Basically I have three pages, index.php enter.php and thankyou.php. The enter.php is a form that exports data to a csv. I need the permission dialog to come straight when the user clicks "Enter" on the index page, if they click accept it will post to the users wall, if they decline it will bring them back to the index page. I'm confused where to put all of my code and how to use the classes? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need a Facebook access token for this code to work. Add your token where `My Access token here` is in the following code:

```
$attachment = array(
'access_token' => 'My Access token here',
'message'      => '',
'name'         => 'My Wall Post Header/Title Here',
'caption'      => 'Small caption here',
'link'         => 'http://www.mywebsite.org',
'description'  => 'Wall Post Details Here',
'picture'      => "http://www.mywebsite.org/images/logo.gif",
);
```

You can get access tokens [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Comment: Hi thanks, what permission to generate the access token would I need to post to the other users wall?